# Applying joins conditionally in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2008-r2

I have some set of records, but now i have to select only those records from this set which have theeir Id in either of the two tables.

Suppose I have table1 which contains

```
Id  Name
----------
1   Name1
2   Name2
```

Now I need to select only those records from table one
which have either their id in table2 or in table3

I was trying to apply or operator witin inner join like:

```
select * 
from table1 
inner join table2 on table2.id = table1.id or
inner join table3 on table3.id = table1.id.
```

Is it possible? What is the best method to approach this? Actually I am also not able to use

```
if exist(select 1 from table2 where id=table1.id) then select from table1
```

Could someone help me to get over this?

Comment: You are half way through :select * from table1 inner join table2 on table2.id =table1.id 
inner join table3 on table3.id=table1.id.

Comment: read about joins here :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38549/difference-between-inner-and-outer-joins/27458534

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would be inclined to use `exists`:

```
select t1.*
from table1 t1
where exists (select 1 from table2 t2 where t2.id = t1.id) or
      exists (select 1 from table3 t3 where t3.id = t1.id) ;
```

The advantage to using `exists` (or `in`) over a join involves duplicate rows.  If `table2` or `table3` have multiple rows for a given `id`, then a version using `join` will produce multiple rows in the result set.

Answer (score 2):

Use `left join` and then check if at least one of the joins has found a relation

```
select t1.* 
from table1 t1 
left join table2 t2 on t2.id = t1.id 
left join table3 t3 on t3.id = t1.id
where t2.id is not null 
   or t3.is is not null
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the most efficient way is to use `UNION` on table2 and table3 and join to it :

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM table1 t1
INNER JOIN(SELECT id FROM Table2
           UNION
           SELECT id FROM Table3) s
 ON(t.id = s.id)
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you can use below SQL as well:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    dbo.Table1
WHERE   id Table1.IN ( SELECT  table2.id
                FROM    dbo.table2 )
        OR Table1.id IN ( SELECT   table3.id
                   FROM     Table3 )
```